# How to locate your dinosaurs that you tamed using force tamed when you die?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I can't find my dinosaurs, I play on a private server tamed an alpha raptor using force tame and tamed a sarco then a few other 20 dinosaurs. The whistle doesn't work and I know they are near my corpse but I can't find it. Is there any way to use admin commands to teleport to my corpse, and if not, anyway to find my corpse without it. I just want my dinosaurs back.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you forced tamed or not. A problem that could occur is that it glitched under the map. If not, you could probably use corpse finder (a mod that spawns a beacon that you can see further than the original one). If you can't find it you could always find another one.